# xmonad hotkey to span monitors

Tags: xmonad

I can make a window span all three monitors by floating it and dragging it across with the mouse. It would be nice to add a keybinding to do this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to look into the xinerama option

Comment: i'm using xinerama and really like the way it abstracts the desktop from the monitor and lets you swap them around. I'm looking for how do with the kyboard the equivalent of alt-right-click...drag across all threee displays

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the XMonad.Actions.Onscreen and the XMonad.Actions.CycleWS plug-ins.  Documentation [here](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/).